# Mongoose populate works with exec() but not with cursor()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

The following works just fine:

```
Campaign.find({
   ...
})
  .populate('summary')
  .lean(true)
  .exec()
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

However, if I try to do the same with cursors:

```
var cursor = Campaign.find({
   ...
})
  .populate('summary')
  .lean(true)
  .exec
  .cursor()

cursor.next().then(function (data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

`summary` field is not populated, returning only the `ObjectId` referenced by the model.

### Edit

Here are the relevant parts of my schemas:

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
var campaignSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  summary: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'summaries' },
  // ...
}

var summarySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
}

var Campaign = mongoose.model('Campaign', campaignSchema, 'campaigns')
var Summary = mongoose.model('Summary', summarySchema, 'summaries')
```

Is this by design? Or am I missing something?

### Edit #2

If it's worth something, I'm using Mongo 3.0.12 and Mongoose 4.4.20.

Comment: can you show your schema also?

Comment: There you go...

Answer (score 1):

you should use `Schema.Types.ObjectId` instead of `ObjectId` and ref value should be `Summary` instead of `summaries` then it should be working.

```
var campaignSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  summary: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Summary' },
  // ...
}

var summarySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
}

var Campaign = mongoose.model('Campaign', campaignSchema)
var Summary = mongoose.model('Summary', summarySchema)
```

and for `cursor` no need to use `.exec`

```
var cursor = Campaign.find({
   ...
})
  .populate('summary')
  .lean(true)
  .cursor();

cursor.next(function(error, doc) {
  console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, `ObjectId` is an alias to `Schema.Types.ObjectId`... I forgot to include it. Furthermore, why does it work when I use `exec`, but not with `cursor`?

Comment: dose it correctly populate when used `ref: "summaries"` instead of `Summary`?

Comment: This was also missing in the example... I've edited the question... Sorry for the confusion... It's a huge schema, I had to extract only the relevant parts.